# C: Define function which takes array of constant strings, returns randomly selected one

Tags: c

I'm having trouble working with strings in C. Here is my function which takes an array of strings and returns a randomly selected one. randint(int n) is a function which returns a random integer from 1 to n.

```
int rand_word(const char ARR[]) {
    int r = randint(sizeof(ARR));
    return(ARR[r]);
}
```

Here is my main():

```
int main() {
    const char *WORDS[3];

    WORDS[0] = "a";
    WORDS[1] = "b";
    WORDS[2] = "c";

    printf("%s", rand_word(WORDS));

    return 0;
}
```

I expected to see either "a", "b", or "c" printed.

```
[Error] cannot convert 'const char**' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int rand_word(const char*)'
```

Essentially my confusion is between data types. What have I done wrong? Thanks.

Comment: check carefully the types of the argument and the returned value type of your function. what is it supposed to take? What it is supposed to return?

Comment: In a C function prototype, `char ARR[]` is really just syntactic sugar for `char *` because a function call converts an array into a pointer to the first element of the array. So `sizeof(ARR)` will have the same value as `sizeof(char *)`. You need to pass the actual length as a separate parameter.

Comment: If `randint(n)` returns a number from 1 to n, be aware that array index operations in C start from index 0, not index 1, so you would need to subtract 1 from the return value of `randint(n)` to get an index in the range 0 to n-1.

Comment: when you pass an array to a function it decays into a pointer with no information about the size of the original array.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that rand_word is 100% wrong lets just deal with the error message.

YOu have a function that is declared as taking at char array (char[]) as an argument. You are passing it and array of pointers to a char array. Thats not valid.

Change rand_word to accept `char *ARR[]`

now rand_word is wrong

a) sizeof (ARR) will always be 4 or 8. Its the size of a pointer. you cannot inspect a pointer to an array and determine the length of the array. Pass in a second argument with the length

b) The function returns an int. It should return a pointer to a string

Answer (score 1):

1. In a C function prototype, `char ARR[]` is really just syntactic sugar for `char *` because a function call converts an array into a pointer to the first element of the array. So `sizeof(ARR)` will have the same value as `sizeof(char *)`. You need to pass the actual length as a separate parameter.
2. If `randint(n)` returns a number from 1 to n, be aware that array index operations in C start from index 0, not index 1, so you would need to subtract 1 from the return value of `randint(n)` to get an index in the range 0 to n-1.
3. Your `rand_word` function takes a pointer to the first element of an array of `char` and returns a single element of the array (a single `char`) converted to an `int`. But your caller passes the function a pointer to the first element of an array of `const char *` and expects it to return a `const char *` (judging from the use of the `"%s"` `printf` format specifier).

Putting that altogether, your `rand_word` function should look something like this:

```
const char *rand_word(int n, const char *ARR[])
{
    int r = randint(n) - 1; // randint returns number in range 1 to n
    return ARR[r];
}
```

Since your `WORDS` array has 3 elements, your `printf` call should be something like:

```
    printf("%s", rand_word(3, WORDS));
```

You could also use this macro to get the length of an array (doesn't work on pointers):

```
#define ARRAY_LEN(ARR) (sizeof (ARR) / sizeof (ARR)[0])
```

Then your `printf` call can be something like this:

```
    printf("%s", rand_word(ARRAY_LEN(WORDS), WORDS));
```

Comment: this looks pretty neat. Can you please explain this arithmetic? (sizeof (ARR) / sizeof (ARR)[0]).

Comment: @fotang It is the size of the whole array (`(ARR)`) divided by the size of a single element (`(ARR)[0]`), giving the number of elements (i.e. the length) of the array. The parentheses around the macro parameter `ARR` are to avoid operator precedence problems when `ARR` expands to something other than a simple identifier. The `sizeof` operator itself doesn't need parentheses when operating on an object, so I didn't give it any. (However, `sizeof` does need parentheses when operating on a type, rather than an object.)

Answer (score -1):

First, you're providing a `*char[]` (or `char[][]`) for the parameter to `rand_word()` instead of a `char[]`.

Then you return a `char` (`ARR[r]`).  You should use `%c` instead of `%s` in your `printf()` statement because of this.

Either that or change `const char ARR[]` to `const char* ARR[]`.

Comment: Not my DV, but your notation `*char[]` is peculiar and not C.  Maybe you had `char *[]` in mind?

Comment: that may be the case.  i've always used `*char[]` instead of `char*[]`.  i.e. `char *thing[]` instead of `char thing*[]`